# Exponential Function Regression

Tags: regression

I need to find the exponential function y = c0e^(c1*x) using fit in Mathematica for the data points {1850, 1.3}, {1900, 1.6}, {1950, 3.0}, {1980, 4.4}, {2000, 6.0}}.

Comment: data = {{1850, 1.3}, {1900, 1.6}, {1950, 3.0}, {1980, 4.4}, {2000, 
    6.0}};
fit = FindFit[data, a  Exp[b x], {a, b}, x]

Comment: I tried that code!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
data = {{1850, 1.3}, {1900, 1.6}, {1950, 3.0}, {1980, 4.4}, {2000, 6.0}};
f = a Exp[b (x/1850-x0)];
fit = FindFit[data, f, {a, b, x0}, x];
fit0 = f /. fit // Simplify
gr0 = ListPlot[data, PlotStyle -> Red];
gr1 = Plot[fit0, {x, 1850, 2000}];
Show[gr1, gr0]
```

so the adjust is

$$
y = 0.330376 e^{22.8667 \left(\frac{x}{1850}-0.955521\right)}
$$

or also

$$
y = 1.0711413556895699\times 10^{-10}e^{0.0123604 x}
$$

[image]

Comment: data = {{1850, 1.3}, {1900, 1.6}, {1950, 3.0}, {1980, 4.4}, {2000, 6.0}};
f = a Exp[b (x/1850-x0)];
fit = FindFit[data, f, {a, b, x0}, x];
fit0 = f /. fit;

when I coded this out I didn't get the coefficeints of c and c1

Comment: $c_0 = 1.0711413556895699\times10 ^{-10}$ and $c_1 = 0.012360370484277862$ You should simplify.